# Erlang convert ejabberd XML structure to string

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

The Erlang representation of my XML message is like the below:

```
{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"to">>,<<"x">>},{<<"id">>,<<"aaf6a">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"wewe">>}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"time">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:server-time">>},{<<"stamp">>,"2015-06-23T22:48:24Z"}],[]}]}
```

How can I convert it into simple text format:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" type="chat" to="x" id="aaf6a">
<body>wewe</body>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ejabberd `xml:element_to_binary/1`:

```
xml:element_to_binary({xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>},{<<"to">>,<<"x">>},{<<"id">>,<<"aaf6a">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"wewe">>}]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"active">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates">>}],[]},{xmlcdata,<<"\n">>},{xmlel,<<"time">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:server-time">>},{<<"stamp">>,"2015-06-23T22:48:24Z"}],[]}]}).
```